# Which of these sets is bigger?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am a fourth year computer science student and I am taking second year level maths because they are very useful for computer stuff.

At the end of the linear algebra lecture the Prof left us with a question to think about.

Which of theses two sets is "bigger" (contains more elements?).

The set of positive integers from $0$ to $\infty$ OR the set of reals inclusive $0$ to $1$?

My intuition tells me they are the same size (infinity).

I suck at math but its so useful for computer vision (my field) and I am trying to get a better understanding of pure maths.

Thanks!

Comment: Both sets are infinite, but some infinities are bigger than other infinites.

Comment: You might as well get rid of the "inclusive". It only adds $2$ elements to an already infinite amount of them...

Comment: Think of it like this: just like "finite" is a general term that includes sets of size 1, 2, 3, etc, "infinite" is also very general term. Not all infinite sets are the same size

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key question here is what do we mean by "size". How do you count an infinite set? Aren't they both infinite?

When we count a finite number of things, one way of thinking about it is that we designate each thing with a counting number - so to count the number of people in a room, I designate each person a consecutive number and the number of people in the room is the largest number. There are $n$ people in a room if we can map the people in the room with the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Mathematically, we can extend this concept. Two sets have the same "size" or **cardinality** if there is a bijection - i.e. a "complete" one-to-one mapping between the two sets.

For example, there is a bijection between the set of integers $\mathbb Z$ and the set of even integers $2\mathbb Z$ given by $$\mathbb Z \to 2\mathbb Z\\n\mapsto 2n$$so we can say that these two sets have the same cardinality, even though $2\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z$.

However, not all infinite sets have the same cardinality, and it turns out that there is no way of creating a bijective map between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb N$ - the positive integers. One way of proving this is called **Cantor's diagonal argument**: suppose we could assign each decimal number a unique positive integer. That means that we could write down a complete ordered list of decimals:

1) $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$
2) $0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$
3) $0.c_1c_2c_3\ldots$
$\vdots$

But I can write down a decimal that differs from each of these: $0.(a_1 + 1)(b_2+1)(c_3 + 1)\ldots$ (where I'll take $9+1=0$ - i.e. addition modulo 10)

Then I've written down a number that wasn't on my list as it's different to every number on the list in at least one place... but that can't be true if my list contained *every* decimal... so my list can't have contained every decimal.

Answer (score 4):

You can "put" all integers $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$ into the reals in $[0,1]$ by assigning $x$ to $1/x$. You eventually see later, that the other way round it is completely impossible.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Who said anything about continuous? He just missed that $0$ was in the set, so you need $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x+1}$

Comment: Sorry - I misread the question as looking for a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of positive integers is denoted $\mathbb{N}$. The set of reals between 0 to 1 is denoted $(0,1)$ (exlusive) or $[0,1]$ (inclusive). This is a very basic (but not trivial) problem in infinte set theory and you can find its solution in every book on this subject. The final answer is:
$$ | \mathbb{N} | < |(0,1)| = | [0,1] | $$
and it is proven by Cantor's diagonal argument.

Google for Cantor's Diagonal or read in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_diagonalization

Comment: |(0,1)|=|[0,1]| 
This is the stuff that makes my head hurt.  wouldn't (0,1) have 2 less elements?

Comment: Yes, but both are infinite sets. Consider a simpler problem: which set is bigger: $A = \{ 1,2,3,4,... \}$ or $B = \{ 3, 4, 5, ... \}$?

Comment: Maths neat.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Map the integers $n$ to $1/n$ (except $0$), they all fit into $[0, 1]$, but still have all irrational numbers in that range...

Comment: Ooh, since I can put 1/n into [0,1] As long as I can find 1+ example(s) of numbers that fits I can say the set [0,1] is bigger?

Comment: The thing is that all integers fit into the range, leaving plenty of space, making it obvious that $\Bbb R$ is larger. So yes, get your example, maybe $e^{-1}\in \Bbb R$, and then there are more reals than fractions $1/n$...

Comment: I can map $[0,1]$ into $[0,2]$ "leaving plenty of space". They still have the same cardinality. You need to show the non-existence of an injection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb N$, not the existence of an injection the other way round.

Comment: @Mathmo123 hm does it suffice to have one example that doesn't map back to $\Bbb N$?

Comment: You would need to show that there is no example that maps back to $\mathbb N$... just because there is one that doesn't, doesn't mean that all of them don't